# passing value to the classes without navigating

Tags: android, flutter, dart

For the code below, on the press of the icon of the first class, I want to send data to the second class. First-class just contains the data that needs to pass to the second class. There is no way or not allowed to navigate from first to second class. The only option to navigate to the second class is from the third class. I tried creating a constructor in the second class and implemented
second page(data:_getData.text). But there is no way i am getting the value. I am just getting null.

```
**First class**

onPressed: () {    setState(() => _getData.text);
                                           **SecondPage(data:_getData.text);**
                                  }

**Second class**

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
   String? data;
   SecondPage({this.data});

    @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState(data);
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
   String? data;
 _SecondPageState(this.data);

**Third class**
Get.to(SecondPage)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you change a lot of states, you would use bloc or any state management. because it is good for the app. if you want only this thing, you use the below code.

First Screen

```
class FirstScreen extends StatefulWidget {
const FirstScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<FirstScreen> createState() => _FirstScreenState();
}

class _FirstScreenState extends State<FirstScreen> {
String title = "no value_f";
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              title = "value";
            });
          },
          child: Text("Press")),
      SecondScreen(title: title),
    ],
  ),
);
 }
  }
```

Second Screen

```
     class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {
     String title;
     SecondScreen({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

      @override
     State<SecondScreen> createState() => _SecondScreenState();
      }

    class _SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {
     @override
     void initState() {
      widget.title = "no value";
      super.initState();
        }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Text(widget.title);
   }
   }
```